# Why doesn't disown operate on the last job if I background it?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, job-control

Say I have backgrounded a process e.g. VIM with ctrl-z. Then I start an xterm using the following command `xterm &> /dev/null &`.
If I just type disown then I will lose my vim process. I instead have to type the PID of the xterm process to disown it.

Is there any way to get round this or is there a reason this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How to fix (short version)

You have  couple of ways to do it:

- With `%-` you will ask to disown the last *background job*.

  ```
  xterm &> /dev/null & disown %-
  ```
- With `$!` instead you will ask to disown the last *executed job* (through its PID).

  ```
  xterm &> /dev/null & disown $!
  ```

<sup>So it will require to write a couple of characters more, but at least you can  choose which ones :-)</sup>

#### The reasons

The reason is all here: **when you execute a job sending it to background with `&`, essentially it doesn't change the current job, but only the previous one.** The current job remains the one that was before.

#### Some words more and an example

You can check what said above with the command `jobs`, comparing its output before and after to have launched a job in background.

- **Before**: let's suppose you have a couple of background processes just running from a terminal (e.g. launched with `dolphin &` and `kate &`).
  Now you start `vim` and you suspend it with  <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.
  The output of `jobs` will be:

  ```
  [1]   Running                 dolphin . &
  [2]-  Running                 kate  &
  [3]+  Stopped                 vim
  ```

  `vim` is the current job, flagged with a **`+`**, and `kate` is the previous one, flagged with a `-`.

  Indeed on the bash reference manual, chapter 7.1 <sup>[[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html)]</sup> is explained that
  *" In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a ‘+’, and the previous job with a ‘-’."*
- **After**: Finally you write your command `xterm &> /dev/null &` (without `disown`).

  Asking to `jobs`, this time it will answer:

  ```
  [1]   Running                 dolphin .
  [2]   Running                 kate 
  [3]+  Stopped                 vim
  [4]-  Running                 xterm &> /dev/null &
  ```

  **Note that `vim` is still flagged with a** **`+`** and `xterm` with a `-`.
  The last background job marked with `-` is `xterm` and not any more `kate &`.
- In other words the system acts as if

  - First it runs `xterm`: the new command (`xterm`) becomes the current one and `vim` the previous one.
  - Then `xterm` is sent in background  and the control comes back to the previous one in the list (`vim` with its status) that becomes again the current one and it is marked again with **`+`**. `xterm` instead is the new *previous job* and it is marked with a **`-`**.
  - At the end you find updated only the *previous job* (-) and not the current one (+).

Since you can call `disown` followed by a job number or by a PID you have the two variants

- `%-`: **the previous job may be referenced using `%-`**, maybe more easy to remember if you think that also in jobs is marked with a `-`
- `$!`: **the PID of the last job that runs in background** is in the special parameter **`$!`** <sup>[[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)]</sup>.

The command `disown` will accept both.

**References**

- [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)